# Control access on certain users

Tags: c#, asp.net

My website is mainly divided into 3parts. One for administrator, mostly maintenance pages to update database. One for general users who browse the page with accounts logged in. One is for anonymous to browse and check out our products. How could I restrict the users/anonymous to get to my admin pages and how do I restrict anonymous to purchase?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set up 3 folders(Admin, Users, Anonymous), then you put the web forms that you want those people who could have access to in the folder. After that you need to set up your users, roles and access rules in the asp.net configuration(Website->Asp.net Configuration). Now, you should see web site Administration tool, go to security. You could set up your users, roles, and access in there. It would allow you to restrict users to certain web forms.